# jquery, Image slide effect

Tags: jquery, image, user-interface, slider

As someone who is quite new to jquery, I'm trying to make a simple slider for an image area but the effect I'm using does the whole div. How would i make this only effect the image.

```
var bgArr = ["../css/img/head/1.png", "../css/img/head/2.png"];
var i = 0;

var interval = self.setInterval("swapBkgnd()", 5000)

function swapBkgnd() {
if (i > (bgArr.length - 1)) {
    i = 0
    $("#header").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")").effect("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}
else {
    $("#header").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")").effect("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}
i++;
};
```

I would like it to keep the old image there as the new one slides in aswell if possible.

http://fear.kennyist.com/ - Whats happening now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you to have a look on this tutorial. It also has a jquery slider tutrial.

you can build your own slider in a day

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-obligatory-slider/